# Clean the CSS that was added while loading Ajax content

Tags: javascript, html

I am appending an HTML document into my current page using Ajax, and removing those added divs when the close button is pressed. The problem is that when I close, the divs are removed from the document but the CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` are not removed, and the number keep increasing as I load and unload Ajax content. How to completely remove the loaded document with the header content (css, js) of that page?

edit: i dont know why people dont want to answer but they just come to negative voting. 
this is the code that i have used to add(append the html document)

```
$(function(){
              $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
                pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
                $.get(pageurl, function(html) {
                          $(html).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn(500);
                      }, 'html');

                //to change the browser URL to the given link location
                if(pageurl!=window.location){
                  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
                }
                //stop refreshing to the page given in
                return false;
              });
            });
```

and this code to remove the divs

```
function close(){

        $("#mainContent").fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
        window.history.back();
} ;
```

Comment: If you have a bunch of `<style>` elements, then put them inside the `<div>`s that they style so when you remove the `<div>` you remove the associated `<style>` elements as well.

Comment: i want to add them in header only, IDE shows warning, and i dont want to do that, any alternate solution?

Comment: Could you show the code you used to add and remove the content?

Comment: How are the link elements added? What do the original HTML documents look like? What are you using to append and remove the code?

Comment: @matthias.p: i have edited with my code that retrieves content and appends..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the document that you are attempting to add/remove, but I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div id="main-content">
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

So when you add that content, the whole thing is inserted. When you remove it, you are only removing the `div#main-content`. To remove everything, two ideas come to mind:

- Preferably, wrap the document in another `<div>` and remove that instead
- Alternatively, you could select `<link>` elements that are siblings of the 'div#main-content`, but that has the potential to be more unpredictable.

If the document you are adding *doesn't* look like that, then please explain in the OP what it does look like and where the `<link>` elements are coming from.

If you are doing something like a HTML preview in another page, look into creating an iframe instead. Use AJAX to create a temporary URL as the source. The advantage is that you avoid conflicts that occur when you effectively merge two DOMs.

Comment: i am doing the same thing as you mentioned above, 
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="mainContent">
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
     </div>
    </body>
    <html>

i want to append the mainContent to my page with the styles that are added in in it, and remove them completely with their style, but only mainContent getting removed, as i have written the code for it, dont know how to remove complete html doc, everytime I load this content divs are getting removed but the added styles remains as it is.

Comment: @user1531746 as mentioned in the answer, if you're trying to render another HTML doc inside another one, use an iframe. There are so many issues with trying to just 'merge' the DOMs - doctypes, conflicting IDs, styles intended for one DOM instead affecting the other, and so on. Use AJAX to write the other DOM to a temporary file, and render that inside an iframe.

Comment: @user1531746 iframes are definitely supported by all modern browsers, and there are no plans to remove it. There was some discussion about removing it from the HTML5 Strict spec, but in the end they kept it. A lot of advertising uses this technique (including Google), so that the publisher and advertiser content does not conflict.  In other words, I would say that you are safe to rely on iframes for at least the next few years.